# Git no clone option

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am new to Git. Maybe the solution is simple but not for me:)

I downloaded Git 1.9.4 and TortoiseGit-1.8.11.0-32bit.
After right click on folder I can't find TortoisseGit option "clone".
What's more, I can't run "git clone" and any other git command in command line. I receive message:
"'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command".
Anyone has idea why?

Comment: I can't help you with the context menu problem, but you can't run Git from the Windows command line because the Git installer doesn't update your PATH variable. I'm sure there are tutorials on how to fix that, or you could use the Git Bash tool that ships with Git

Answer (score 1):

Cloning allows one to get a copy of code from a Remote Repository to your working directory or local repository (e.g. your laptop). For TortoiseGit, navigate to the  location on your laptop where you want to create the working directory or local repository, then **Right-Click** -> **Git Clone**.

I believe Jason Baker knows the reason for the "git is not recognized as an internal or external command" message. Here is what I would try on **Git Bash** once you check the path variable:

1. `git clone --help` - to figure out the syntax
2. `cd` - to Remote Repository
3. `ls` - verify location of files
4. `git clone` - type complete syntax here